# Using Gigya API with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, social-networking, gigya

For one of my projects I'd like to try out Gigya as my social network connection provider and am writing my app using Node.js.  Has anyone done this?

Gigya provides a JavaScript API that is intended to be used on the client.

http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API

It should be possible to adapt that for server side use.

Comment: It's likely possible to adapt the client side JavaScript API, but imho it would be better to use their REST API.

Answer (score 4):

Gigya's client side javascript is intended to be run in the browser as much as possible, since they perform 2 part authentication using cookies set by their domains. You can try to port it to run server side, but none of the public methods will work as advertised.

I've written a wrapper for their REST API using their proprietary authentication that I've been using in a work project for a few weeks: https://github.com/jproulx/Gigya-Node-SDK -- note that not everything has been tested thoroughly as I've only needed to use a subset of the socialize services on the server side. It should serve as a good jumping off point to bootstrap something for your needs.

Comment: how to add extrafields attribute in this call?

Answer (score 1):

Gigya does not yet have an official Node SDK. However, I've written an SDK that implements the entire service.

In addition to the standard APIs, it contains special support for streaming data from Accounts & DS.

Git: https://github.com/scotthovestadt/node-gigya

Install with "npm install gigya".